# Python in Windows does not recognize ".." as a shorthand to search parent directory

Tags: python, windows, directory, path, filesystems

Using
VSCode v1.53.2
Python 3.9.1 and 3.8.5 in two separate environments
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

When trying to access the data in my project folder using ".." as a shorthand for the parent folder in python, I get the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\Resources\\Environmental_Data_Deep_Moor_2012.txt'`

I have tried to access this file using `pathlib.Path`, directly on the `open(<path>, 'r')` statement. And nothing works.

If I use the absolute path, it suddenly finds the file.

The script also finds the file if I use the interactive interpreter, with the `#%%`, and the relative path.

If I place the file in the same folder as the code or even in a subfolder it works fine with the '.' shorthand.

I have tested all these variants with a new file, with fresh folders and the issue persists.

Comment: Use `import os; os.path.join()` to create your paths. It works on Linux and Windows. Also your problem might stem from you being in a different working directory.

Comment: @TinNguyen Thanks, mixing your solve with @YashvanderBamel I finally realised that the problem is got to do with how I am opening the project folder on VSCode. I was able to get around it with `os.getcwd()` and `os.path.join()` .

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to add the parent directory to the path. But this is temporary, you might have to append this code at the start of your script permanently.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '/..')
```

After this you can call the parent directory directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it did not work. It seems to be related to the way VSCode is trying to run the code.